# React Native + Typescript - the Haste package was found. However the module X could not be found

Tags: typescript, react-native, package

I got this error and I've tried many config but nothing works:

```
 BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: Error: While resolving module `screens/BulletinScreen2`, the Haste package `screens` was found. However the module `BulletinScreen2` could not be found within the package. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * `C:\Development_Projects\atlas\src\screens\BulletinScreen2(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
  * `C:\Development_Projects\atlas\src\screens\BulletinScreen2\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)`
    at resolveHasteName (C:\Development_Projects\atlas\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:173:9)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Development_Projects\atlas\node_modules\metro-resolver\src\resolve.js:63:20)
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Development_Projects\atlas\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:111:31)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Development_Projects\atlas\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:260:43)
    at Object.resolve (C:\Development_Projects\atlas\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:177:21)
    at Graph._resolveDependencies (C:\Development_Projects\atlas\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:432:35)
    at Graph._processModule (C:\Development_Projects\atlas\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:218:38)
    at async Graph._addDependency (C:\Development_Projects\atlas\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:314:20)
    at async Promise.all (index 4)
    at async Graph._processModule (C:\Development_Projects\atlas\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:263:5)
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Please tell me how can I fix this, I've tried to change `babel.config.js` and `tsconfig.json` but still same error, and I did put `package.json` with name:folder_name but not working...

Comment: Did you manage to fix this error? For me it happened after I moved a file to a different folder within the project.